# docker-compose INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Am trying to use docker-compose command and bring up container. But am facing error INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory!. Am not able to pull, stop, rm or UP and container. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you include if you are using docker for windows/mac or natively on linux?

Comment: There was no space left on my VM. Hence it was failing.

Comment: How do you solve that @RK3?

Comment: I deleted all the docker images that i had pulled from repository. docker rmi <IMAGEID>

Answer (score 51):

I was suffering from the same issue. It turned out that I'd ran out of Disk Space.

All I needed to do was clear down the old containers and images by running the below commands. I ran these on my Docker directory and everything was good afterwards.

**Remove Containers Command:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remove all stopped containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
# Remove all containers
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

*Command options:*

`--force` or `-f`: Force the removal of running container (uses `SIGKILL`).

`--volumes` or `-v`: Remove the Volumes associated with the container.

`--link` or `-l`: Remove the specified link.

**Remove Images Command:**

```
# Delete all images
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

*Command options:*

`--force` or `-f`: Force removal of the image.
`--no-prune`: Do not delete untagged parents.

**System Prune Command:** -- Suggested by `Ryan Allan` in comments.

```
#!/bin/bash
#System Prune
docker system prune
```

`--all` or `-a`: Remove all unused images not just dangling ones.

`--filter` Provide filter values (e.g. 'label==') <-- From API 1.28+

`--force` or `-f`: Do not prompt for confirmation.

`--volumes`: Prune volumes.

**Base Command:**

`docker`: The base command for Docker CLI.

Code referenced from [Docker remove all images and containers](https://techoverflow.net/2013/10/22/docker-remove-all-images-and-containers/)

Comment: This *is* a diskspace issue. However, I'd recommend checkig all the causes for storage getting filled up before removing containers and images

Comment: `docker system prune` cleans everything up nicely too, including volumes and networks

Answer (score 10):

You have run out of space on the disk where the Docker cache is located, you can verify this by running the command `df -h`. To fix this you need to clean disk space, for example you can clean the Docker cache, look at small script below.

This solution is based on `Popeye` answer, but with force stopping of all images:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Force stop all containers
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
# Delete all containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
# Delete all images
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

But as `Ryan Allen` told, better to use the `docker system prune` for removing of all containers, images and networks. So the final view of script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Force stop all containers
docker kill `docker ps -q`
# Delete all containers, images and networks
docker system prune
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

To delete the space used by Docker on Ubuntu, you can follow these steps:

1. **Remove stopped containers:** First, you can remove any stopped containers by running the container subcommand as following  in your terminal:

```
sudo docker container prune -f
```

Here the above command removes all stopped containers that are not associated with a running container.

**2. Remove unused images:** Next, you can remove any unused images by running the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo docker image prune -a -f
```

above command works including dangling images (i.e., images that are not associated with any container) and unused images (i.e., images that are not being used by any container).

3. Remove unused volumes: Finally, you can remove any unused volumes including volumes that are not associated with any container. You can run the following command in your terminal:

```bash
sudo docker volume prune -f
```

This command will remove all unused volumes,

By running these commands, you should be able to free up some space used by Docker on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

For people using docker inside a VM, it might also be that you might have inadvertently disconnected the drive that the VM image is stored on. As was my case. In such an event, it is best to stop the VM, make sure the drive is attached, and then restarting.

Comment: Good point. Up!